# How can I PWM 4 LEDs from 0 to full brightness using a two axiz resistive joystick?

Tags: led, pwm, joystick

- I am trying to use the Arduino MAP function to allow me to PWM 4 LEDs between 0 and full brightness. I guess the tricky part is that the joystick neutral position is at the venter of the range of the potentiometers so the analog voltage to the inputs is at +2.5V when the joystick at neutral). Ideally I want to make a red LED that is associated with the Y axis to go from 0 to full as the joystick is pushed away. Similarly, I want a blue LED associated with the Y axis to go from 0 to Full on when the joystick is pulled toward me. I want to duplicate that action for the X axis with green and yellow LEDS but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to compensate for the 2.5V offset* I hoped I could just use mapping of the values.

Comment: Yes, just map 2.5-5 to 0-255 and analoWrite that value

Comment: `int x=analogRead(A0);if (x >=512) red=(x-512)/2;` etc.

Comment: Thanks to all who have responded. I have tried Sim Son's approach and as unsuccessful. I will have to test the other techniques.I'll report back on progress.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of steps you need to go through:

1. Read the ADC to get the joystick position
2. Subtract 50% of the full range (512) to get a ±512 value
3. Note the sign to get the direction
4. Take the absolute value to get the distance
5. Subtract a small amount to create a "dead zone" in the centre of the joystick
6. Map the result to 0-255 for the PWM.

The code might look like (note: untested):

```cpp
int y = analogRead(0);    // Get the current value
y -= 512;                 // Subtract 512

int pin = 2;              // Unless otherwise told, use pin 2
if (y < 0) {              // If it's negative...
    pin = 3;              //    then we'll use pin 3 instead
}

y = abs(y);               // Take the absolute value (discard the sign)
y -= 20;                  // subtract 20 for a dead zone
If (y < 0) y = 0;         // zero any negative
y = map(0, 492, 0, 255);  // map the new full range of 0-492 to 0-255
analogWrite(pin, y);      // light the LED on the pin we chose above.
```

And do the exact same thing for X with different pins.

Comment: If you subtract 20 from y before mapping, won't that cause some negative values of y? (The range would be -20 to 492 instead of 0-512.) What does map do with out-of-range values?

Comment: I'd suggest changing  `y -= 20;` to `if y <= 20 y = 0;` instead.

Comment: Good question. You should do it at 0.